# OneNote 2013 no longer saving screenshots

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Recently my onenote has stopped saving screenshots to my notebook. The keyboard shortcut (win + shift + S) still works to put them on the clipboard but it does not save them anymore. If it matters 0ct 08 2017 was the last time it worked correctly. I have restarted several times since then.

Comment: I have the same problem on one of my machines and haven't resolved it yet.  It used to prompt for the location to send the screen clip, then it just quit asking and always put it to the clipboard.  For me, the options in Send to OneNote are all still set to "Always ask where to send".  Are yours set to that as well?

Comment: Mine are set to "to new page in section quick notes (user's notebook)" I can manually add pages so its not full.

Comment: Try a repair install of Office.